# display arabic websites in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing a web browser, my problem now is that arabic web sites cannot be displayed correctly in android, I know that mini opera browser can display arabic web sites, so is anyone know what can I do to make webview reconize the arabic font ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arabic websites display fine on devices that supports arabic, supporting the language shouldn't be your concern that much it should be the device's manufacturer's

usually if someone uses your app , chances are that he/she already got a device that displays arabic properly so it should work fine

also ICS (android 4.0) supports arabic natively

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying my browser in my phone sum sung galaxy Gio with android version 2.3.4, my application don't display arabic websites, but the same web sites are displayed correctly in opera mini browser (in the same device), so why in your opinion that happens?

Comment: Opera mini works differently , it's not exactly a browser .. Opera mini opens the site on their server, compress it and then send it to your device , you may imagine that as sending you an image of the site instead of the site

Comment: thanks a lot for the information, so I will try do the same for my application